# Non stopping "Failed to get the memory usage" messages when I run Eclipse IDE from Debian in WSL

Tags: eclipse, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rights

All is in the title. It looks like a permission problem, likewise related to running under WSL. What should I do to solve this please?

Note : I have tried also Liclipse which works without any error message.

Additional information :

- WSL under Windows 10, with Debian 11.2
- Eclipse equinox, here is the `eclipse.ini` content:

  ```
    -startup
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.400.v20210924-0641.jar
    --launcher.library
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.2.400.v20211117-0650
    -product
    org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
    -showsplash
    org.eclipse.epp.package.common
    --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    --launcher.appendVmargs
    -vm
    plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.linux.x86_64_17.0.1.v20211116-1657/jre/bin
    -vmargs
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
    -Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
    -Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
    -XX:+UseG1GC
    -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
    --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
    -Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
    -Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
    -Xms256m
    -Xmx2048m
    --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
  ```

Answer (score 0):

WSL2, Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on Windows

It's a **HORRIBLE** "fix", but it gets rid of the annoyance!

```
$ ./eclipse 2> /dev/null &
```

Hopefully the message is benign and no other Eclipse errors of import are going to the command line.

Comment: If you wanted to *just* suppress that particular message (but still see other errors), you could probably pipe the stderr to `grep` instead and filter that message from the output.